# What does it mean to be stationary?

Tags: terminology, reference-frames, definition, speed

I'm looking for a simple answer. What do we regard a stationary. Do we mean an object that is not moving noticeable from the viewers perspective because then a parked car would be considered stationary, but (assuming it's on earth) the earth is rotating and those at the circumference where the spin is greatest are traveling 1 038 mph and the earth itself is moving with the Milkyway at 600 000 mph. I have a bunch of other questions but I rather not put them all in one post, but do we really account for theses other speeds or do we ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

This term is used all the time in introductory classical physics. In that context, *stationary* usually means not moving in the laboratory frame. Thus, a block sitting on a table not doing much would be referred to as being stationary.

If one studies relative motion, then *stationary* could mean not moving in whatever frame you're discussing.

Comment: Based on what I said in my question wouldn't the block still be moving since (assuming it's a lab on earth) it's on earth and the earth is moving?

Comment: @user34873 Yes, that is true, but you need to establish why we should think it's a problem.  Museums sometimes use pendulums as time keeping devices, demonstrating that the "lab" frame isn't entirely inertial.  However, on the milliseconds time frame is it sufficiently inertial for the purposes of some specific experiment.

Comment: If stationary is defined as an object with no motion and the object does has some type of motion then isn't there a problem?

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer:  motion is relative thus, there is always an implied reference.  In other words, if you read or hear the phrase "X is stationary", you should immediately think "stationary with respect to *what*?".

Most often, it is the case that an unqualified "stationary" means "at rest with respect to the measuring apparatus" or "with respect to the lab".  But, of course, the apparatus or lab is not an absolute reference and thus, *the lab is relatively moving with respect to ... a lot of other things*.

In fact, all we can really say is that two or more objects are moving *relative to one another or not*; there is no absolute rest with which to say that something is absolutely stationary or moving.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, whether or not an object is stationary is relative to the observer?